# copy folder containing 10 mp3 files from Assets to SD-card

Tags: android, assets, android-sdcard

I'm developing an android free drum kit app for `Electrum Drum Machine/Sampler`.

I need to copy a folder containing `10-20` mp3 files from Assets to `SD-card`.
I need the folder containing the files to go here "sdcard/electrum"
also where exactly do I insert the path  "sdcard/electrum"  in the code!

I'm new to coding but catching on real fast I can code my UI's, button, pages, but I just need a little help thank you!

here is my code...

```
package com.example.newsampletest;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        copyAssets();

    }

    private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("files");
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        for(String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream("files/"+filename);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

> im get a error from my device "installation failure. please check the file and ensure that there is sufficient space of the moblie for installation"

That suggests that your APK file is too large, and your device lacks sufficient internal storage for it.

You can:

- Uninstall existing apps to try to make room, or
- Try using shorter audio clips, or
- Reduce the audio clip quality (e.g., reduce the bitrate), or
- Use fewer audio clips, or
- Do not package some or all of the clips with your app, but instead download some on first run to external storage, or
- Play around with the [app install location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html), though I am not completely certain that this will help in your case

Comment: i just testing my code out. so only have one file in assets. the apk is only 249 KB

Comment: @antony: Then the problem is more with your device being out of room.

Comment: "installation failure. solved..thanks. still need to get the assets to go here "sdcard/electrum"